# c++ 11 regex print all groups

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

My question is really simple, I can't make c++ 11 regex to return all groups present in the string.

code below is what I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  auto fixMessage("8=FIXT|9=69|35=5|34=18|49=102|56=asd|115=TESTTESTTEST|52=20170810-15:36:22.500867816|1409=42|");
  std::regex e ("(([0-9]+)=(.*?)\\|)+?");
  std::cmatch element_match;

  if(std::regex_match(fixMessage, element_match, e)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < element_match.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << i << ": " << element_match[i] << '\n';
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this only prints this

```
0: 8=FIXT|9=69|35=5|34=18|49=102|56=asd|115=TESTTESTTEST|52=20170810-15:36:22.500867816|1409=42|
1: 1409=42|
2: 1409
3: 42
```

while I would like to have all groups not just the last one .. 
 [here is a cpp.sh url](http://cpp.sh/9llmd)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a combination of `regex_match` and `regex_search`. The first can be used to check the validity of the whole string, the second can be used to extract all the matching groups:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() 
{

    std::string s("8=FIXT|9=69|35=5|34=18|49=102|56=asd|115=TESTTESTTEST|52=20170810-15:36:22.500867816|1409=42|");
    std::regex re("((\\d+)\\=([^|]*?)\\|)+?");

    if (std::regex_match(s, re)) 
    {
        for (std::smatch m; std::regex_search(s, m, re); s = m.suffix())
        {
            std::cout << m[1] << "\t\t" << m[2] << "\t\t" << m[3] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I tweaked the regex expression a little bit. Because of "grabby" regex nature you need to use `([^|]*?)` rather than `(.*?)` to capture everything between `=` and the following `|` This becomes apparent when you want to check the overall format of the string with `regex_match`

This prints:

```
8=FIXT|         8               FIXT
9=69|           9               69
35=5|           35              5
34=18|          34              18
49=102|         49              102
56=asd|         56              asd
115=TESTTESTTEST|               115             TESTTESTTEST
52=20170810-15:36:22.500867816|         52              20170810-15:36:22.500867816
1409=42|                1409            42
```

Comment: That is not bad, but I'm focused on the performance issue, I guess Ill develop my own regex parser.

Answer (score 0):

A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.

You have to iterate with `std::regex_search`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see e.g. [this C++ regex reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) you will see that

> `regex_match` ... attempts to match a regular expression to **an entire character sequence**

and

> `regex_search` ... attempts to match a regular expression to **any part of a character sequence**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

The [`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) function will only find *one* match. You should use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead.

Comment: Can you define in regex_search to not match ANY if the whole string doesn't match the regex? because the way I see it, I would have to use the regex_match to check if the whole string matches and not just one part.